# Kernel module can't be loaded - "invalid module format"

Tags: kernel, driver, cross-compilation, modules

Headline: I've cross-compiled a kernel module for the Raspberry Pi, but on attempting to load it, I get the following error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module testmod.ko: Invalid module format
```

Detail:

I've got the kernel source for the kernel I'm running in the following way:

```
$ zcat /usr/share/doc/raspberrypi-bootloader/changelog.Debian.gz | grep '* firmware as of' | head -1
  * firmware as of 951799bbcd795ddf27769d14acf4813fdcbe53dc
```

This gives the firmware git hash.  I then get the corresponding kernel hash:

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/951799bbcd795ddf27769d14acf4813fdcbe53dc/extra/git_hash -O - 2>/dev/null
20fe468af4bb40fec0f81753da4b20a8bfc259c9
```

On my Ubuntu (18.04) host, I then:
    $ git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
    $ git fetch rpi-4.1.y
    $ git checkout 20fe468af4bb40fec0f81753da4b20a8bfc259c9
    $ scp pi@raspberrypi.lan:/proc/config.gz .
    $ zcat config.gz > linux/.config
    $ cd linux
    $ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- oldconfig
    scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
    #
    # configuration written to .config
    #

Then in my module source dir:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -C ../linux M=$(pwd) modules
make: Entering directory '/home/tkcook/RasPi/linux'
  CC [M]  /home/tkcook/RasPi/testmod/testmod.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/tkcook/RasPi/testmod/testmod.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/tkcook/RasPi/testmod/testmod.ko
make: Leaving directory '/home/tkcook/RasPi/linux'
```

I can't see what I've done wrong here.  Am I possibly using the wrong version of GCC?

Comment: If it is the GCC version, I'm out of luck - the raspberry pi 4.1.19 kernel was built with GCC 4.9.3 and Ubuntu only supplies the ARM cross-compiler in version 5 and up.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using that old kernel? Current RPF kernel is 4.14.x. You can find RPF toolchain at https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708. Also see https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md about cross-compiling kernel

Comment: The work I was doing happened to be on an older embedded device that used a 4.1 kernel in a jessie distribution.  There was no particular reason for that though, it was what I happened to have to hand.  I've confirmed that using the GCC 4.9.3 from the RaspberryPi tools github and upgrading to stretch and 4.14 fixes this.